# Xcode 4 Inspector Panel tells me "No Selection" no matter what

Tags: xcode4

I have a window, a label, a button, and an NSObject.

The first thing I want to do is change the NSObject's class to that of my custom controller.

The thing is, I can't seem to select it. Whatever object I select, the inspector panel says "No Selection". Why? I'm baffled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface builder in XCode 4 is incredibly buggy.  I'm also having frequent issues like this.  Have you tried closing XCode and re-opening your project?  Sometimes, resizing the entire XCode window also seems to reset the interface builder layout.

Make sure you're selecting the objects from the XIB document panel (Where it says "Objects") on the left.  Sometimes clicking the actual UI controls doesn't catch in the inspector panel, for whatever reason.

Comment: It most likely was a bug. The problem went after restarting.

Answer (score 23):

accepted answer did not work for me, but answer by 'NSExplorer' did ([In Xcode4, the new interface builder says "no selection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540504/in-xcode4-the-new-interface-builder-says-no-selection)).  i slightly modified answer from 'NSExplorer'

.. switch to another (non IB) file in the current tab
.. switch back to the IB file (eg. Main.storyboard)

the Attributes Inspector will magically show in the new tab.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked on Xcode 7. Thanks, @tmr :)

Comment: Same exact solution worked for me in Xcode 7. Has anyone filed a radar yet?

Comment: Close tab and reopen IB in another tab worked for me Xcode 7.1.

Comment: the above fix Worked in latest xcode 7.2 - I have submitted the bug to Apple.

Answer (score 6):

I just had to close the assistant editor and the debug area and then it magically showed up. If you don't have the assistant editor open then all you need to do is open it, then close it again. That should fix it too.

If you don't know what the assistant editor is I have highlighted it in red:

[image: Assistant editor in red]

Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the bottom, debugger stretched all away to the top. It said "no selection." By Taping on hide/open bottom debugger twice, you can get the main component back again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple windows, close the storyboard file and open it again, it worked for me