# In Xcode4, the new interface builder says "no selection"

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, xcode4

I am using the xcode 4.02 for iPhone programming. In the new interface builder, when I click a button (or any other GUI-element) and go to the "attributes inspector" it says "no selection". For a while I thought I could solve the problem by saving the nib-file, but it does not always work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I get this occasionally too. I have used File->Close "MyView.xib", then reopen with some success. Restarting XCode seems to do it as a final option.

Comment: +1, Okay, I'll try this next time.

Comment: No sure fire solution yet here. It will snap out of it without restarting xcode but I don't know the magic incarnation

Answer (score 33):

There seems to be a bug in Attributes Inspector in Xcode 4. When this happens to me I usually do this:

- Switch to another (non IB) file in the current tab
- Launch a new Tab (cmd T)
- Open the original IB file in this new tab

The Attributes Inspector will magically show in the new tab.

Comment: Just downloaded XCode 7 and this bug is still present. Your solution works great, thanks!

Comment: Just had the same issue in Xcode 7, and this solution worked!

Comment: Also had similar problem in Xcode 7.  Was able to, in the same tab, switch to a non-IB file and then switch back.  Attributes inspector showed.,

Comment: Using 7.0.1, I had the same problem and your solution worked. I'm happy I found your Answer quickly and didn't waste more than 5 minutes on it.

Comment: man I feel so dumb... I rebooted everything and reset everything, almost uninstalled xcode...

Comment: I can't believe Apple hasn't fixed this yet (if a radar has been filed, that is).

Answer (score 3):

I just had to close the assistant editor and the debug area and then it magically showed up. If you don't have the assistant editor open then all you need to do is open it, then close it again. That should fix it too.

If you don't know what the assistant editor is I have highlighted it in red:

[image: Assistant editor in red]

Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do you open the inspector window by clicking the 3 button in the views group? Once you do that the attribute inspector is shown on the left and you can now open the nib files and select any gui element.

Comment: Yes,this is the way I open the inspector. Usually it works, but sometimes it does not work. I have restarted my xcode and now it works.

Comment: Thats great. Happy coding. Must be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you click the GUI element after making the attributes inspector visible?

Comment: I think I have tried all possible combinations... I have restarted my xcode and now it works again..